# Using bluebirdjs with Google Cloud Datastore node client library

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-datastore, bluebird

I am having a strange issue trying to use bluebirds promises with google's cloud client libraries. 
After digging around Google's libs, I noticed in the common functions, there is a util file with promisify functions. 
I assume these are being used to promisify the datastore acess functions, as they can be used as a promise. 
My problem comes in because I am writing a Google Cloud Function which executes based on a PubSub trigger. 
At the end of the function I need to execute the `callback()` function to 'end' the function.

I wanted to use bluebirds `finally()` api on the promises to make sure callback is always called. But, when trying to access the datastore it returns it's own type of Promise and not a bluebird promise, even if I try call:

```html
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const Datastore = Promise.promisifyAll(require('@google-cloud/datastore'));
const datastore = Promise.promisifyAll(
Datastore({
projectId: 'xxxx'
}));
```

But this doesn't seem to 'replace' Google's promises with bluebirds. Is there a way to do this?

My Current work around:

```html
dothing(value)
.then(function(){
  return doAnotherThing(anothervalue);
})
.then(function(){
  // Done
  callback();
})
.catch(function(){
  // Something went wrong
  callback();
});
```

I know this isn't *that* much more than a `finally()` but it still feels a little inelegant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, that was a little embarrassing. So, instead of taking full responsibility for making such an obvious mistake, I will blame the bluebird documentation. (It's not, it's entirely my fault for not reading properly)

Anyway, in order to use bluebird with datastore, I just needed to append `Async` to the function call.

```js
function doTheThing(keys){
  return datastore.getAsync(keys);
}
```

Super simple